# jQuery select.val() always returns first option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, popover

I woking on an app to creat a roster. Inside this, there will be a table with fields for every date. When clicking on an empty field, a popover opens with all available doctors for this date (depending on wishes e.g.). This popover contains two selections.
When I try to get the content of these, jQuery unfortunately always returns the value of the first option of each select (regardless of the selection).

The code for this is a bit spaghetti-like but looks like this:

ejs:

```
            <div id="popover-content-<%= day.date.getDate()%>" class="hide">
            <p>select two for shared duty</p>
            <select id="emergency-department-first-<%= day.date.getDate()%>" class="form-select new-plan-form-select">
                <option value="0"> </option>
                <%doctors.forEach(doctor => {%>
                    <%if(doctor.emergencyDepartment){%>
                        <%wishList.wishes.forEach(wish => {%>
                            <%if(wish.doctorId === String(doctor._id)){%>
                                <% if(!wish.noDutyWish.includes(day.date.getDate())){ %>
                                    <option value="<%= doctor._id%>"><%= doctor.name%></option>
                                <%}%>
                            <%}%>
                        <%})%>
                    <%}%>
                <%})%>
            </select>
            <select id="emergency-department-second-<%= day.date.getDate()%>" class="form-select new-plan-form-select">
                <option value="0"> </option>
                <%doctors.forEach(doctor => {%>
                    <%if(doctor.emergencyDepartment){%>
                        <%wishList.wishes.forEach(wish => {%>
                            <%if(wish.doctorId === String(doctor._id)){%>
                                <% if(!wish.noDutyWish.includes(day.date.getDate())){ %>
                                    <option value="<%= doctor._id%>"><%= doctor.name%></option>
                                <%}%>
                            <%}%>
                        <%})%>
                    <%}%>
                <%})%>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
        <button type="submit" data-duty="emergency-department" data-date="<%= day.date.getDate()%>" class="bnt btn-success popover-btn" >OK </button>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.popover-btn',function(){
    duty = $(this).data("duty")
    date = $(this).data("date")
    first = $("#"+duty+"-first-"+date).val()
    second = $("#"+duty+"-second-"+date).val()
    console.log(first)
    console.log(second)
    return false
})
```

I think there is not an error in my code-logic, because if I only query for

```
$("#"+duty+"-first-"+date)
```

it returns the right selection. But I can't get the selected option.

Can anyone please tell me, what I did wrong? :(

update:
also not working with

```
$("#"+duty+"-first-"+date).find(":selected").val()
```

Comment: instead of doing `.val()` on your selects try doing `.find(":selected").val()` .. that's the correct way to isolate the option selected and then get the corresponding value

Comment: unfortunately still returns "0" as value =(

Comment: if you simplified your code in a way that didn't include that server side portions but just the final html rendered and shared that I could show you exactly how to fetch the value you are looking for. Unfortunately there are not enough information to correctly interpret why you read 0 as value. `$('#select_id option:selected').val()` is the way to retrieve the selected option of the #select_id element but if it didn't work you have something odd in your html and I can't see it there yet because you shared the template not the html

Comment: for example there's no evidence of the data attributes that you are using to build the selector to get the select